# How to convert a css such as "select::-ms-expand" dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code that I want to use in javascript code like "`$('select').css('-moz-appearance','none');`". I searched for some solutions via google, but I wasn't able to find a way. Some tips or examples would be great ! I would love to hear from you.

```
<style>
        select::-ms-expand {
            display: none;
        }

        select {
            -moz-appearance: none;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `::-ms-expand` is a **[pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)**, and thus **[technically doesn't exist in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21709814/2341603)**. In terms of a JavaScript solution that doesn't require **any** CSS support, your only option would be to dynamically inject the desired rule into the stylesheet via JavaScript's `addRule`:

```js
$('select').css('::-ms-expand', 'none');
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE") !== -1 || navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Trident") !== -1) {
  document.styleSheets[0].addRule('select::-ms-expand', 'display: none;');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option>1</option>
</select>
```

Note that the addition of the rule will throw a warning on Chrome and Firefox, but will work in Internet Explorer. As such, you should also confirm that the user is running Internet Explorer by checking against `MSIE` and `Trident` in their `navigator.appVersion`.

Hope this helps! :)